# Elastic search 5.3 create index with one shard

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I am trying to create an index with only one shard from windows os. I'ge got the code from the [elastic website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html) I've changed only the simple quote to double and 3 to one and my curl looks like this:  curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/twitter?pretty" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":2}}}

When I run this I got the following error:

```
{
"error" : {
"root_cause" : [
  {
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse content to map"
  }
],
"type" : "parse_exception",
"reason" : "Failed to parse content to map",
"caused_by" : {
  "type" : "json_parse_exception",
  "reason" : "Unexpected character ('s' (code 115)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.ByteBufStreamInput@f220023; line: 1, column: 3]"
 }
},
"status" : 400
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it work from fiddler 4 like a charm

Answer (score 2):

As I'm familiar with operating on `postman` here it goes:

**Postman**

select the PUT method

> localhost:9200/twitter

Move to the body section of postman click on `RAW` radio button then select JSON from the drop-down next to `binary` radio button

now all you need to is send the settings in JSON format

```
{"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":2}}}
```

> **note:** don't use quotes while sending the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/twitter?pretty" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"settings":{"index":{"number_of_shards":1,"number_of_replicas":2}}}'
```

Try that, you need to quote your data (the -d)

Comment: adding the simple qoute I'm getting an error with reason : "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes"

Comment: @Radu Remove `-H` option or you should provide data as `json` file instead of `string`.

Comment: @Radu - I don't know about that, you have something wrong with Elasticsearch I'd guess.  If I were you I'd re-install Elasticsearch and re-create the index.

Comment: @avr I've found the new issue I've getting is because it's a string and somehow the server did not expect a string.

Comment: @mikeb thank you, I will try ;) It works from fiddler calls